# in textbox how when when I press ENTER submit the Form and when I press shift+ENTER insert new line

Tags: javascript, php, html

how in textbox when when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> submit the Form and when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> insert new line like facebook comments and posts

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make textbox as textbox and submit at the same time like posts in Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309587/how-to-make-textbox-as-textbox-and-submit-at-the-same-time-like-posts-in-faceboo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might have a solution for your submit on <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Assuming you're using jquery :

```
 $('your-input-selector').keypress(function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       $('form').submit();
     }
 });
```

Javascript :

The HTML input

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="myKeyPressHandler(event)">
```

Javascript function

```
function myKeyPressHandler(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }
}
```

- Edit 1

Here your solution for the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> combination:

Jquery:

```
  $('your-selector').keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13 && e.shiftKey) {
                alert('shift enter pressed');
                //Do your work here
            }
        });
```

Non-Jquery :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="myKeyUpHandler(event)">
```

Javascript function:

```
function myKeyUpHandler(e) {
    if (e.which === 13 && e.shiftKey) {
        alert('shift enter pressed');
                //Do your work here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure in jquery : $('your-textbox-selector').val(''); in javascript  :document.getElementById('your-id').value = '';

Comment: @AmrEzz i invite you to take a look at my edit i put the shift+enter combination for you.